# Control Widows Media Device Flash Light

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, windows

I am trying to create a simple application which will have the functionality to switch on and off the flash light in a Windows Media Device. 
I have initialized the camera as following:

```
    var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);

    var rearCamera = devices.FirstOrDefault(item => item.EnclosureLocation != null &&
                                                item.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);
    if (rearCamera != null)
    {
        DeviceName.Content = rearCamera.Name;
        FlashButton.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();

        await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
        {
            VideoDeviceId = rearCamera.Id
        });

        LowLagPhotoCapture lowLagCaptureMgr = null;
        // Image properties
        ImageEncodingProperties imgFormat = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();

        // Create LowLagPhotoCapture object
        lowLagCaptureMgr = await mediaCapture.PrepareLowLagPhotoCaptureAsync(imgFormat);

    }
```

And to switch on the flash I have written the following code:

```
        var MyVideoDeviceController = mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController;



        var MyTorch = MyVideoDeviceController.TorchControl;
        var MyFlash = MyVideoDeviceController.FlashControl;

        if (MyTorch.Supported)
        {
            MyTorch.PowerPercent = 100;
            MyTorch.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (MyFlash.Supported)
            {
                MyFlash.PowerPercent = 100;
                MyFlash.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Flash and Torch Support", "Flash and Torch");
            }
        }
```

But seems both TorchControl and FlashControl are not supported in the code. I am not sure if am using the right APIs too. I am trying to run this on a Motion F5m - Tablet PC

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The `TorchControl` is used for *constant* video light, so if you're taking a photograph, it's not the most appropriate control to use. One reason is that on many devices, video light will be dimmer than a photo flash, but especially because on some devices, the torch will only turn on while a video recording is in progress. Depending on the capabilities of the device, this may interfere with the ability to take photos.

You have the right idea setting `MyFlash.Enabled = true`, but just to be safe, I would also set `MyFlash.Auto = false`, so that the flash will fire each time, and not only when it's dark.

The [CameraManualControls](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraManualControls) sample on the Microsoft GitHub repository shows you how to use the Flash and Torch controls, and many more. It targets Windows 10, though, so if you're on 8.1 you'll have to adapt the code or upgrade your tablet.

Now, all of the above is assuming that the device you're running your app on has flash support in the first place. When you say that the controls are not supported, that means that the camera driver on the device is not advertising the capability to Windows. I assume that the built-in Microsoft Camera app doesn't allow you to use the flash either?

I see the manufacturer of your tablet lists an "Illuminator Light" on their [camera specs list](https://www.motioncomputing.com/us/features/motion-f5te-digital-camera-and-web-camera), but there is a chance that the only way to control it is through their proprietary application. In that case you'd have to reach out to them for support.

Comment: Thanks @Mike that was really informative. Just FYI my intention is to keep the light source on as a torch. I am gonna try your links. Thanks again for the info. Keep the good work.

Comment: Hi @Mike, do you know of any drivers that can expose the device to windows?

Comment: Drivers are not usually interchangeable just like that, especially if you're looking to enable some functionality. Now, Microsoft does deliver a generic camera driver, so you could try to either revert to that one (by uninstalling the camera in Device Manager and deleting the driver software) or if you're already running the Microsoft driver, installing the driver provided by the manufacturer. Does the manufacturer provide an app that can use the flash? Is the flash not available in the built-in camera? If so, you should contact them to ask for better drivers.

Comment: Yes there is a camera app that's provided by the manufacturer with flash light while taking pictures. Are there any other alternatives to Torch/Flash control since they are not supported. I even tried WPFMediaKit kit but I could not find anything that can enable the cam at all.

Comment: And just to confirm, the Microsoft built-in "Camera" app doesn't trigger the flash either and has no option to control it, correct? It appears that the manufacturer didn't implement the driver to expose all capabilities the hardware offers through the MediaCapture APIs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557607%28v=vs.85%29.aspx You could try searching the manufacturer website for updated camera drivers.